# nasm x86 assembly (with qemu) - runtime crash on changing segment register

Tags: assembly, nasm, qemu

I am trying to write my own bootloader, and in the effort of making it possible to debug things, I thought I would start by getting into protected mode and drawing a pixel to the screen. I want to use vga mode 13 and have tried the following code (in real mode) which worked as expected :

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

boot:
  mov ah, 0x00
  mov al, 0x13
  int 0x10
  
  mov ax, 0xa000
  mov es, ax
  mov bx, 0x0000

.loop:
  mov cx, bx
  mov [es:bx], cl
  adc bx, 0x0001
  
  jc .halt
  jmp .loop

.halt:
        cli
        hlt

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

This code was compiled with `nasm -f bin minboot.asm -o minboot` and run with `qemu-system-x86_64 -fda minboot`. This produced exactly the output I was expecting. My next order of business was to try to do the same thing in protected mode, and then hopefully jump into using C instead of assembly. (I have also tried, with some success, to load more from the disk by reading more disk sectors. I omitted that in this attempt for clarity)

The following program was my attempt to do some of that

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

boot:
mov ax, 0x0013
int 0x10 ;set mode 13

mov ax,0x2401
int 0x15 ;a20 line 


cli ;disable ints 

lgdt [gdtptr]
mov eax,cr0
or eax,0x1
mov cr0, eax ;set protected mode 


mov eax, DATA ;data seg 

mov es, eax
mov fs, eax
mov gs, eax
mov ds, eax
;mov ss, eax
mov esp, 0xFFFFF0 ;near end of data seg 
jmp cstart

gdtstart:
dd 0x0 ;null
gdtdata:
dw 0xFFFF ; limit 
dw 0x0 ;base bottom 2 bytes
db 0x0 ;base next 
db 10010010b;access, data, grows up, writable, kernel level
db 11001111b; 4kib blocks  blocks, 32 bit mode, and max limit 
db 0x0; end of base 
gdtcode:
dw 0xFFFF ;limit
dw 0x0 ; 16 bits of base 
db 0x0 ;24 bits of base
db 10011110b ; code, kernel, grows up(?) readable
db 11001111b ; blocks, 32 bit, max limit 
db 0x0 ;end of base (32)
gdtend:

gdtptr:
dw gdtend - gdtstart
dd gdtstart 

CODE equ gdtcode - gdtstart
DATA equ gdtdata - gdtstart

cstart:
  mov ax, 0xb000
  ;cli
  ;hlt
  mov gs, ax

  mov [gs:0x0000], byte 0x01 
  hlt 

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

As is probably obvious, this is cobbled together from several tutorials and answers from this site. I have several small questions.

First, are segment registers like es,ds,cs, etc pointers to the proper GDT table entry, or are they indexes of said entries?

Secondly, when I omit the `;cli \n ;hlt` near the end, qemu crashes instantly and retries, only to crash again. Commenting `mov gs,ax` prevents this, and makes qemu halt on a black screen, as expected. What about the line `mov gs,ax` causes this runtime crash? (Note I also tried with es and fs, which to my understanding are extra segment registers and should not have broken anything) Placeing `cli` and `hlt` AFTER `mov gs, ax` does not prevent the crash, so it is definitely that line that is causing problems. Furthermore, why is it that `mov [0xa000:0000], byte 0x01` causes a compile time error with `invalid segment override`?

Thirdly, I am sure my GDT is extremely scuffed, so if that is the cause of the problem I am not surprised, but any pointers in that direction would be appreciated (xkcd.com/138 jokes aside).

I suspect I am the fool here, but frankly I am having trouble untangling what I suspect to be a combination of several problems. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `jmp cstart` is a relative (NEAR) 16-bit jump. It is advised to use an immediate far jump to reset `cs` after switching modes. Your setting of `gs` (`ds`, `es`, `fs` are fine too) uses the value `0xb000` in `ax` which is not a valid selector value (would be a valid segment base in Real or Virtual 86 Mode). Selectors are indexes/offsets into the GDT or LDT; for the GDT the offsets in the table (every 8 bytes) exactly match the scaled index values, if you mask off the low 3 bits of the selector. You should use a loop like `label:` \ `hlt` \ `jmp label` to ensure the machine "halts".

Comment: `mov [0xa000:0000], byte 0x01` or the slightly more readable equivalent `mov byte [0xa000:0000], 0x01` are invalid because there is no encoding of the `mov` instruction with an immediate segment value. (Only direct far branches `jmp` and `call` can encode an immediate segment value. None of the instructions with explicit memory operands can encode immediate segment values.) Even if there was, `0xa000` is not a valid selector value when you're already in Protected Mode.

Comment: Correction: The jump may be optimised to a relative (SHORT) 8-bit jump. However, the same recommendation to use an absolute FAR jump applies.

Comment: Another issue I found: `gdtstart` should be followed by a qword (8 bytes, 2 dwords) of zeroes. Are you sure your example uses a single dword here yet does not fail on `mov es, eax` ? Perhaps the machine does not validate the descriptor (GDT entry) on loading with a could-be valid selector (below the GDT limit).

Comment: So if I want the selector for `gdtdata`, would it be `0x0008 ` (first bit after 3 masks), aka the table entry at index 1? Also, could you elaborate on what a far jump looks like in this context? I know my code should start at `0x7c00` in memory, but how can I get an absolute address for `cstart`? Thanks so much

Comment: The *gdtptr:* starts with a word to represents the limit of the table (not the size). You need to write `dw gdtend - gdtstart - 1`. You're missing the **-1**.

Comment: (After corrections; 1st entry must also hold **8** bytes) the *gdtdata* will be the 2nd entry in the table. You use it via: `mov ax, 8` `mov ds, ax`.

Comment: and then my final write command to vga mode13 ram should be `mov byte [ds:0xa0000], 0x01` ? That doesn't seem to have any effect, although it has stopped crashing after all of these fixes.

Comment: and dumping at 0xa0000 gives me zeros. hmmm

Comment: Once your code enters protected mode, you still need to inform the assembler to start using 32-bit mode encodings. Insert the `use32` directive after changing `CR0`. If you do this an instruction like `mov byte [0xA0000], 1` will start making sense. (You don't need the override prefix when it's `DS`)

Comment: `bits 32` does that. moving it after the `cr0` assignment doesn't change anything

Comment: `ds:` within an explicit memory operand is useless (the default is already `ds`) and wasteful (NASM will encode a useless `ds` prefix). After you have loaded `ds` with the corrected `DATA` selector (which should evaluate to 8 indeed, index = 1, scaled index = 8, offset from GDT start = 8) then accessing with a 32-bit offset like in `mov byte [0xa0000], 1` should work. Far jump looks like `jmp CODE:cstart` but note that before the `cstart` label you should put a `bits 32` directive if your GDT entry comments accurately indicate the `CODE` selector will point to a 32-bit code descriptor.

Comment: The `bits 32` goes only before a section you have reached by a **far** jump with a 32-bit code selector. Not immediately after the `mov cr0, eax` because up until after the far jump instruction you still have to provide code defaulting to a 16-bit operand size. Especially the far jump itself needs to be encoded as segimm:imm16 (without an opsize prefix 66h) or segimm:imm32 (with an opsize prefix).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the gods among men who answered in the comments to the original post, My problem is now solved. The final version of my code is below

```
bits 16

section .boot
boot:
mov ax, 0x0013
int 0x10 ;set mode 13

mov ax,0x2401
int 0x15 ;a20 line 


cli ;disable ints 

lgdt [gdtptr]
mov eax,cr0
or eax,0x1
mov cr0, eax ;set protected mode 


mov eax, DATA ;data seg 

mov es, eax
mov fs, eax
mov gs, eax
mov ds, eax
;mov ss, eax
mov esp, 0xFFFFF0 ;near end of data seg 
jmp CODE:cstart

gdtstart:
dq 0x0 ;null
gdtdata:
dw 0xFFFF ; limit 
dw 0x0 ;base bottom 2 bytes
db 0x0 ;base next 
db 10010010b;access, data, grows up, writable, kernel level
db 11001111b; 4kib blocks  blocks, 32 bit mode, and max limit 
db 0x0; end of base 
gdtcode:
dw 0xFFFF ;limit
dw 0x0 ; 16 bits of base 
db 0x0 ;24 bits of base
db 10011110b ; code, kernel, grows up(?) readable
db 11001111b ; blocks, 32 bit, max limit 
db 0x0 ;end of base (32)
gdtend:

gdtptr:
dw gdtend - gdtstart - 1
dd gdtstart 

CODE equ gdtcode - gdtstart
DATA equ gdtdata - gdtstart

bits 32
cstart:
  cli
  mov ebx, 0xa0000

looplabel:
  mov [ebx], byte 0x05
  inc ebx
  mov ecx, ebx
  xor ecx, 0xa00FF
  jecxz stop
  jmp looplabel

stop:
    hlt 
  jmp stop

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

The solutions hung on me not understanding how addresses work and my GDT being messed up.

Thanks so much

Comment: "the gods among men" I'm not a man. Anyway, after `xor` you don't need `jecxz` but can use just `jz` because the `xor` instruction sets the Zero Flag if it results in a zero. Also, you should write to `ss` too, which is commented out in your code yet.

Comment: Why did you drop your `ORG 0x7C00`? Also `lgdt [gdtptr]` could still fail if `DS` (that you don't explicitely setup) happens to be unsuitable.

Comment: @ecm: I notice you didn't dispute the god/goddess part of that over-the-top praise :P

Comment: Guess I should have gone with "living gods". Oh well. I dropped `org 0x7c00` as I can specify that as part of the linking process (I think).